# Manually edit/add the artist art for groove music

Tags: windows-10-mobile, groove

- Groove music doesnt seems to recognize some artists and thus is not showing the album arts for them.

[image]

- so i thought of manually doing them, i found an article on **reddit** regarding this, but its for PC users. [LINK](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/525y0e/how_to_change_groove_music_artist_images_and_more/)
- the link to edit was *C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\ImageCache\20*
- i cant seem to find the same link on phone. I have enabled full file access into os using interop tools.
- Is there a similar link in to groove music of phone, where it holds the cache memory?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

Finally, after some meddling, i found the link for imae cache for groove on mobie. it's `Computer\Windows phone\Phone\Data\USERS\DefApps\APPDATA\LOCAL\Packages\Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\ImageCache\20.`

I can edit existing artist art to a newer user defines one, but i cant seem to add one with a proper name!

Comment: Thank you for the link to edit the artists images for the computer!
As for the mobile one, is this folder created once you connect your phone to the pc by a cable? How does it work?

Comment: I found the folder under a different path, weird enough, the folder was empty though... im clueless on what to do to set custom artist images. I'll update if I find anything usefull.